# How to pass get parameter via submit button

Tags: html

Hello i have a form which i am receiving parameter from previous page, so i want to pass the both value of the form plus parameter which i have received from from previous page.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$remoteemployeeid = $_GET['RemoteEmployeeID']; // parameter to be pass to next page via submit button

?>

    <form action="Remote Employee Transaction History_exe.php" name="TransactionForm" method="post">    
<table width="1280px" border="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-family:Verdana; margin-top:30px; margin-left:28px;" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td height="99" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle">

      <p><font size="+3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Remote Employee Transaction History Page</font></p>

      </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="32%">Remote Employee Earn Amount:</td>
    <td width="68%"><input type="number" id="earnamount" name="earnamount" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Remote Employee Tax Deduction:</td>
    <td><select name="taxdeduction" id="taxdeduction" onChange="transaction()"><br />
<option selected="selected">Tax Deduction</option>
<option value="2">Two Percent</option>
<option value="7">Seven Percent</option>
<option value="10">Ten Percent</option>

</select></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Remote Employee Amount Payable:</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="number" id="amountpayable" name="amountpayable" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Remote Employee Amount Paid:</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="amountpaid" name="amountpaid" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Remote Employee Amount Remain With Office:</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="number" id="amountremainwithoffice" name="amountremainwithoffice" readonly ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit To Database"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action="Remote Employee Transaction History_exe.php"

change to `action="Remote Employee Transaction History_exe.php?RemoteEmployeeID=<?php echo $_GET['RemoteEmployeeID']; ?>"`

But beware this is very easy to mess with, as you can change the RemoteEmployeeID by just changing the url in the browser addressfield.

A better approach would be to use php sessions.